# Not able to signup through the signin page

Tags: authentication

I have created signin page and after signin the user must go directly to the home page.
But after signin Im not able to go to the home page. Even the user is not signed-in through the signin page.
However if signin is done through the admin, Im able to signin and go to the home page as well.

given below is the views.py file for the authentication app(HAauth)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from HAauth.forms import UserForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

# Create your views here.

class SignUpView(View):   
    template_name='HAauth/signup.html'
    form_class = UserForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home_feed')
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('signin_view')

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)  


class SignInView(View):   
    template_name='HAauth/signin.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home_feed')
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return render(request, self.template_name)
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('home_feed')

class SignOutView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('signin_view')
```

given below is the urls.py file for the Authentication app (HAauth)

```
from django.urls import path
from HAauth.views import (SignUpView,SignInView,SignOutView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('',SignInView.as_view(), name='signin_view'),
    path('signup/',SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup_view'),
    path('signout/',SignOutView.as_view(), name='signout_view'),
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: DOnt know where is the issue. I think somehow the signin is not happening from the signip page. After signip the user is not redirected to the Home and signip page remains visible. Also the user is not signed in that I checked from the Admin. Dont know why the signin is not happening.